# Stable vector of probabilities

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm trying to make a program in scilab (hopefully the same applies to matlab) to get the time where a stable vector is found, I mean, after making several times the product vector and matrix the result will became stable thus wont' change.

I think the best way to do this is with a recursive function so I coded the following:

```
function [R]=vector_stable(v,m,i)
    V=v*m;
    if(V == v) then
        R=i;
        abort;
    else
        vector_stable(V,m,i+1);
    end
endfunction
```

Let me explain that a little a bit, V is product of initial vector and the matrix, if the result is the same as the vector parameter then must return the time when this happened, if is not, it will call the same function with the result as the first parameter. However i'm getting the following error

```
-->R=vector_stable(V,M,0)
 !--error 18 
: Too many names.
```

Is my function correct? Can you help me please?

Comment: I think there is a more efficient way using the eigen-decomposition of the matrix, I'm just not sure how? Maybe you could add the `math` tag to attract the right people :)

Comment: Compute eigenvectors. With or without decomposition, which is only a tool.

Comment: Can you post a sample matrix and vector?

Comment: @Amro - do you work at MathWorks?

Comment: @Ansari: nope, just someone who enjoys coding in MATLAB :)

Comment: Heh just curious, sorry (your profile says you're in/from MA). Your interpolation solution earlier today was impressive. It's been a while since I needed to manipulate and reshape those kinds of matrices so your solution was fun to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't look right. This might be more like it:

```
function [R] = vector_stable(v, M, i)

V = v*M;
if(norm(V - v) < 0.001)
    R = i;
    return;
else
    R = vector_stable(V,m,i+1);
end

return
end
```

Comment: The return statement doesn't work on Scilab, however the condition solved my problem, thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. For a more robust implementation, I'd suggest dividing `norm(V - v)` by `norm(v)` as well and then checking if that is less than 0.001 or whatever threshold you like.

Answer (score 1):

Probably stable does not mean "does not change" but "converges"? Then you cannot test for equality V==v for terminating the loop. You could look at the relative difference between the two vectors and terminate if it gets less than, e.g. 1% or 0.1%.

Do you get the error also when you (for testing purposes) terminate if i==10 instead of V==v?